# Bayesian formulation of best subset regression

Tags: bayesian, lasso, ridge-regression, model-comparison

We know Ridge is equivalent to using a Gaussian prior and Lasso is equivalent to using a double exponential prior.

What is the Bayesian interpretation (implied prior) for the best subset regression? Or is it the case that there is no Bayesian formulation for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This hinges on how you measure the "best" in the best-subset method (i.e., what metric you are using to compare the different models).  Most of the best-subset methods involve minimising some error metric composed of some negative multiple of the log-likelihood and a "penalty" term that may depend on the number of observations and the number of parameters in the model under consideration.  Bear in mind that the best-subset method chooses a model based on the (penalised) maximum likelihood estimator under the model, so it will give you a "best model" along with the corresponding MLE of the parameters of that model.

---

**General form of the best-subset method:** For example, suppose we are considering a model $\mathscr{M}$ with log-likelihood $\ell$ that depends on a parameter vector $\boldsymbol{\theta} \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}_\mathscr{M}$ with length $k$.  Suppose we observe the vector $\mathbf{x}$ composed of $n$ observations.  The error metric used in best-subset method will usually be of the form:

$$\text{Error}(\mathscr{M}) 
= \lambda (n,k) - \eta \max_\boldsymbol{\theta \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}_\mathscr{M}} \ell_\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\theta})
= \min_\boldsymbol{\theta \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}_\mathscr{M}} [\lambda (n,k) - \eta \ell_\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\theta})],$$

where $\lambda$ is a positive penalty function and $\eta>0$ is a positive multiplier of the maximised log-likelihood under the model.  The best-subset method chooses the model $\mathscr{M}^*$ with MLE $\boldsymbol{\theta}^*$ that minimises this error metric.  Thus, if we have some class $\mathscr{G}$ containing models, then we choose the model that satisfies:

$$\text{Error}(\mathscr{M}^*)
= \min_{\mathscr{M} \in \mathscr{G}} \text{Error} (\mathscr{M})
= \min_{\mathscr{M} \in \mathscr{G}} \min_\boldsymbol{\theta \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}_\mathscr{M}} [\lambda (n,k) - \eta \ell_\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\theta})].$$

---

**Bayesian posterior equivalence:** The above method is an estimation method based on minimising an objective function, so it is worth investigating whether we can replicate it using maximisation of a posterior density under Bayesian analysis.  To do this, we find the appropriate form of the prior that gives us the equivalent minimisation, and then we check that this prior is a valid density.  If we have some prior $\pi(\mathscr{M},\boldsymbol{\theta})$ on the model and parameter then this leads to the corresponding posterior:

$$\pi(\mathscr{M},\boldsymbol{\theta}|\mathbf{x}) = L_\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \pi(\mathscr{M}, \boldsymbol{\theta}).$$

Now, if we set $\pi(\mathscr{M}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \equiv \exp( - \lambda (n,k)/\eta)$ then the posterior maximum is:

$$\begin{aligned}
\max_\mathscr{M, \boldsymbol{\theta}} \pi(\mathscr{M},\boldsymbol{\theta}|\mathbf{x}) 
&= \max_\mathscr{M, \boldsymbol{\theta}} L_\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \pi(\mathscr{M}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \\[6pt]
&= \max_\mathscr{M \in \mathscr{G}} \max_\boldsymbol{\theta \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}_\mathscr{M}} L_\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \pi(\mathscr{M}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \\[6pt]
&= \max_\mathscr{M \in \mathscr{G}} \max_\boldsymbol{\theta \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}_\mathscr{M}} [\log \pi(\mathscr{M}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) + 
\eta \ell_\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\theta})] \\[6pt]
&= \min_\mathscr{M \in \mathscr{G}} \min_\boldsymbol{\theta \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}_\mathscr{M}} [- \eta \log \pi(\mathscr{M}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) - \eta \ell_\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) ] \\[6pt]
&= \min_\mathscr{M \in \mathscr{G}} \min_\boldsymbol{\theta \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}_\mathscr{M}} [\lambda (n,k) - \eta \ell_\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) ] \\[6pt]
&= \text{Error}(\mathscr{M}^*). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

Thus, we can see that the best-subset method is equivalent to the [maximum *a posteriori* (MAP) estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) using the prior:

$$\pi(\mathscr{M}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \equiv \exp \bigg( - \frac{\lambda (n,k)}{\eta} \bigg).$$

Now, obviously this equivalence is only going to be valid if this function is indeed a valid probability density function over the class of models and parameters (i.e., it must sum to one and it should not depend on $n$).  This imposes some strict requirements on the penalty function $\lambda$, which in general can depend on $n$ and $k$.  Since $n$ depends on the observed data, if the function depends on this value then we have information from the data in the prior and so this is not a strict Bayesian analysis.  Moreover, if this prior does not sum to one then it is not a valid density and so the equivalence does not hold.  In this case, the only way we can obtain a Bayesian equivalent is to move some of the "prior" weight into the likelihood function, and this means that the equivalent Bayesian model uses a different likelihood function to the best-subset method.

In some cases, such as when using the best-subset method using [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), the above "prior form" does not depend on $n$ but it also doesn't generally sum to one (i.e., it is not a valid density).  In this case it is possible to alter the Bayesian analysis by taking a scaling constant that depends on $k$ out of the prior (to make it sum to one) and putting it into the likelihood function.  Since $k$ depends on the parameter vector, this alters the likelihood function, and so it no longer corresponds to the likelihood under the best-subset method.  Nevertheless, you obtain an "equivalence" of sorts, using likelihood functions that differ by a scaling value that depends on the length of the parameter vector.